# Setting a byte equal to an int and cout

Tags: c++, byte

So I understand that C++  defines a byte as a typedef unsigned char. But I can't fully understand why, after setting a byte variable equal to a int, it couts as a smiley face..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int x = 1;
    byte y = x;
    cout << y;
}
```

I'm sure this has a simple explanation, but I can't seem to find it. Is the first character of the unicode OR UTF8 set a smiley face?

Comment: And what stops you from looking up either Unicode or UTF8?

Comment: `byte` isn't even a valid type within the headers you're showing. Assuming it is what near-everyone defines it (`unsigned char`), you may do well to find how the `std::ostream` insertion operator for that type works.

Comment: `char(1)` is SOH (start of heading) according to ascii table (which is not a printable character).

Comment: Totally forgot about ASCII. I got it now, thanks so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must be using Windows. The character with a code of `1` is the smiley face in [Code Page 437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437), the one used by command windows. Code points `0` through `31` do not correspond to printable characters in Unicode.

Yes, a `byte` is typically defined as an `unsigned char`. When you send a `char` variable (signed or unsigned) to `cout`, it outputs a character and not a number.